# How do I shutdown JBoss Wildfly when I can't access the CLI tool?

Tags: jboss, wildfly, shutdown

I"m using Wildfly 10.0.0.CR2 with Java 8.  I have Wildfly listening for http connections on port 8080 and in the past have used this command to shut down the server ...

```
./jboss-cli.sh --connect command=:shutdown
```

HOwever, occassionally, I'm not able to access this tool, even though the server is still running.  Note the interaction below on my Mac ...

```
Daves-MacBook-Pro-2:bin davea$ ./jboss-cli.sh --connect command=:shutdown
Failed to connect to the controller: The controller is not available at localhost:9990: java.net.ConnectException: WFLYPRT0023: Could not connect to http-remoting://localhost:9990. The connection timed out: WFLYPRT0023: Could not connect to http-remoting://localhost:9990. The connection timed out
Daves-MacBook-Pro-2:bin davea$ telnet localhost 8080
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

My question is, what is a foolproof way to shutdown the JBoss server?  Note I would prefer a method that does not rely on the CLI tool.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I suspect that it is sometimes unable to connect because I can see on the telnet that localhost is resolving to ipv6 first.  have you tried:

```
./bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect controller=127.0.0.1:9990 command=:shutdown
```

Short of that you can always just kill the PID:

```
pgrep -d" " -f "wildfly" | xargs kill;
```

Comment: In Windows I cannot stopping the server with pgrep -d" " -f "wildfly" | xargs kill;

Answer (score 3):

To stop Wildfly:

```
$ ./jboss-cli.sh --connect command=:shutdown
```

Comment: The question was: *How to shut down* and not *How to start*. Flagged as NAA.

Comment: in win10 command line: jboss-cli.bat --connect command=:shutdown